# Communicating with ACR1255U-J1 from PC and sending ISO 14443

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard-reader, nxp-microcontroller

I want to communicate with an NT3H211 tag from nxp. it supports ISO 14443.

I'm not sure how to do this in java using the ACR1255U-J1. There seems to be some drivers on the ACS website but it is not clear to me.

see page 45 of http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT3H2111_2211.pdf

How can I send e.g. WUPA and GET_VERSION via the reader ACR1255U-J1 from windows?

Are there more DEV friendly smartcard readers out there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I send e.g. WUPA and GET_VERSION via the reader ACR1255U-J1 from windows?

You would need to use/develop an application using the PCSC command interface on windows. This works through the CCID standard driver provided by windows to interface with the ACR1255U-J1 over USB. There's open source Java implementations online [like this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsmartcard/) that will allow you to start getting familiar.

> Are there more DEV friendly smartcard readers out there?

The ACR1255U-J1 is actually one of the more dev friendly readers on the market. The problem is that the superset of APIs exposed can be daunting to unfamiliar developers. [Flomio offers a simpler SDK](https://flomio.com/shop/apps/flomio-sdk-basic-turnkey-oem-support/) for mobile devices and web clients to get devs started quickly. It's based on a subset of APIs focused on just scanning a tag. More complex exchanges are then concealed behind a second layer of APIs. This reduces the learning curve and often devs are up and running in a couple hours. You can [check this Forum for further details](http://flomio.com/ask-the-flomies) on how this goes.